# Run fuel php app in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fuelphp

I have a fuel php application created by one of my friend.Now I want to run it on aws EC2 instance(ubuntu).I can run the application using apache2 and its index page is loading.After facebook connect from index page it is supposed to show my fb  friends list. But it is showing a 404 error POST http://ec2xxxxcompute.amazonaws.com/ajax/auth/facebook not found

I can see a get_facebook() method inside controller(/ajax/auth.php).But it is not catching the  method.My top level understanding is i need some url mapping in server level.

Can anyone help me to run the app.Any suggestion will be highly appreciated as a biginner

Answer (score 1):

Are any other URL's loading, or only the index page? If that is the case, it might be a rewriting issue.

Is the default .htaccess file still included in the /public folder? Or did your friend change it?

Comment: .htaccess content:<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

You may not actually be calling your php code at all. Don't you need something like :

```
http://ec2xxxxcompute.amazonaws.com/ajax/auth.php/facebook
```